# Game of Life: Kill the Sun

Tags: computer-puzzle, cellular-automata

Below is an initial state for [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) with a single pulsar. Living cells are white.

[image]

The area marked with red is your base. You are free to modify any of the red cells, but only those, and only in the initial generation. You are not allowed to do anything once the simulation starts.

Your goal is to annihilate every living cell in the grid – in other words, the game must reach a generation where every cell is dead, even in your base. Yet in other, way cooler words:

> You have to construct a rocket to destroy the Sun and everything that was created in the process.

The grid is infinite in every direction, i. e. runaway gliders still count as living.

You may use a brute force algorithm if you really wish, but I don't recommend you to. For one thing, you're up against the halting problem. Besides, finding a good construction all by yourself is fun (at least it was for me).

What I do recommend is downloading a good GoL simulator – solving this with only a paper and a pencil is probably not so much fun.

**EDIT: The puzzle has been solved, but please don't be discouraged from posting alternative solutions. They are still very valuable, as they seem hard to come up with.**

[This puzzle has a continuation, created by kamenf.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31299/game-of-life-move-the-sun)

Comment: Once this puzzle is solved, I will show you my original solution, codenamed "The Dalek". That is, if someone doesn't come up with the exact same solution.

Comment: Even if we restrict ourselves to symmetric solutions, the search space is $2^{30}\approx 1\,000\,000\,000$, juuuust too large for brute-force search.  Maybe a genetic algorithm would be more appropriate =)

Comment: The suggestion of a genetic algorithm was more of a joke, since both it and the game of life are associated with evolution.  Personally I'd just brute-force in order of increasing population, and hope that the solution is sparse...

Comment: @2012rcampion I'd still be happier if you found one manually. I'm sure the CPU you got from your parents isn't half as bad as the one you're sitting in front of. (I meant it the good way!!)

Comment: @2012rcampion Even if you meant it as a joke, now that I think about it, the final phase of how I constructed the (/a) solution was a little similar to a primitive genetic algorithm... Then again, maybe I'm just imagining things.

Comment: Perhaps the solutions may be rated by the number of cells filled in and/or further restricting the red area?

Comment: @Oliphaunt That came to my mind too, but there's just too many aspects to rate based on. Number of cells filled, area occupied, how fast it kills the Sun, how slow it kills the Sun, how many glider guns are created in the process, etc. I think it's a little unfair to pick just one.

Comment: @BaSzAt good point(s). Our sister site PPCG has the [popularity-contest] tag, where the accepted/winning answer is decided by votes at a certain deadline. That could be appropriate here. Anyway I feel that maybe you have accepted an answer a little soon: this could discourage others from posting solutions.

Comment: @Oliphaunt Oh, that's what you mean. Absolutely fair, I might have been too early to put the tick. In which case I'm very sorry. I won't revoke it now, though. That would be a little rude...

Comment: @BaSzAt I understand how you feel and it's up to you. But I've seen it urged many times in similar cases that the tick be removed for a little while longer.

Comment: 2^30 isn't too big for brute force really. In 24 hours on my five year old computer at home I have 400,000 cycles per setting. But I suppose many would turn into the same outcome after a few generations, saving lots of time.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if there is a solution which will destroy a pulsar in ANY frame of its cycle!

Comment: "For one thing, you're up against the halting problem." No, we're not. If a solution exists, then a brute force approach, given enough resources, is guaranteed to find it. Where the halting problem *might* come in is if we're trying to prove that there isn't a solution.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The following is a solution with 34 generations:

> [image] [image]

And, yes, it was really fun to play with it :).

Comment: Beautiful! And you solved it really fast! By the way, it's a different construction from mine. What do you name it? : )

Comment: Let call it "T-Ship". I was fast because I had enough clues - limiting area and I searched for something like ship. This one has two boosters, which in fact produces a lot of fire on ignition ;)

Comment: Nice animation! May I invite you to add animations to the other answers, if you're so inclined? (Or perhaps post instructions... "Give a man a fish...")

Comment: @Oliphaunt On Windows or Mac the easiest way is to use tool like http://www.cockos.com/licecap/ which directly captures screen area to GIF

Answer (score 95):

I found a sun destroyer with just 10 cells filled!

> [image]

It takes 39 generations.

As animation:

> [image]

Comment: Brilliant! If this were code golf, you would be the absolute winner! Thanks for posting it.

Comment: Apparently, you can't do spoiler code blocks. I made a little edit. Hope you don't mind : )

Comment: NP. And welcome to Puzzling SE! (God, I've always wanted to say that)

Comment: Brilliant first answer!

Answer (score 70):

## 6 cells, 43 and 50 generations

I found 11 unique (up to reflection) 6-cell solutions:

> [image]

By the first generation of evolution, they form two identical groups:

- The first, fourth, and last two patterns work by the same method as my previous answer, but are three generations (one pulsar period) slower.  Except for some self-destructing debris they are the same after 17 generations.
- The second group is initially the same as the first group, delayed by one generation.  This group initially interacts with the pulsar much more quickly (at generation 21).

One thing that's notable is that they are all asymmetric, and stay asymmetric for 20 generations (unlike my initial solution which became symmetric on the first generation).  Here's an animation comparing the two groups of 6-cell solutions:

> [image]

## previous solution: 7 cells, 40 generations

> [image]

There are no solutions with fewer than 6 cells (that stabilize within 1000 generations).

Answer (score 61):

## 23 cells, 41 generations, humorous answer

Sorry, I couldn't resist it... The pulsar dies on "magical command" after 41 generations but it takes 23 initial cells.

I apologise for the crudeness of the image. It's my first time using Golly.

> [image: Pulsar dies on command]

EDIT: The next challenge is answered under my registered name Ruutsa

Comment: This one has an independent value on its own even if one didn't know what the original puzzle was.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not get the humor?

Comment: @ByteCommander Rotate the screen by 90°.

Comment: Ah, now I see the "DIE" spell... Nice! :D

Comment: You can request an account merge. (http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 49):

In case anyone is wondering, here is my own solution, which takes 38 generations.

> [image]

(NB: When I made this puzzle, I had no idea if it's even generally solvable. It took me 4 or 5 hours, while having the freedom to change the drawing area as I like.)

By the way, the bottom cells are just for decoration. The following works too:

> [image]

As animation:

> [image]

Comment: For sure this one looks a lot better then mine :)

Comment: @Oliphaunt 38 generations

Comment: Is that a picture of a Dalek from Doctor Who? Nice!

Comment: EX-TER-MIN-ATE!

Answer (score 42):

I made another one, with a mere 8 cells. It takes 44 generations.

> [image]

As animation:

> [image]

Answer (score 38):

## More humorous solutions (destroy methods)

*Sorry, I couldn't resist too*

Call 911 :) 20 cells, 38 generations:

> [image]

Use AI (artificial intelligence), 62 generations:

> [image]

Comment: This is fantastic :)

Answer (score 24):

### 23 cells, 41 generations, humorous answer 2: a special word?

It seems to be a special word. When said [whimsically](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31299/game-of-life-move-the-sun/31339#31339) it moves stars. When said in annoyance it destroys them.

> [image: OH! - blue]

Here's the animation

> [image: Pulsar - OH! - blue]

Answer (score 24):

We have the smallest (6 cells), so to complete the picture here is (probably) the biggest "ship", 46 cells, 40 generations:

> [image]

Comment: i saw a heart at 3rd gen. so i am upvoting <3

Answer (score 4):

I've come across something even better:

> [image: run this and you'll see why]

:)

Comment: Great work, but could you include an animated image like the other posters?  It's hard to see if it's a working answer with just a still shot.