# Game of Life: Move the Sun

Tags: computer-puzzle, cellular-automata

Based on [Game of Life: Kill the Sun](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31247/game-of-life-kill-the-sun)

Conditions are the same:

Below is an initial state for [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) with a single pulsar. Living cells are white.

[image]

The area marked with red is your base. You are free to modify any of the red cells, but only those, and only in the initial generation. You are not allowed to do anything once the simulation starts.

Your goal is to **move** the pulsar so that its center is within area of the base – in other words, the game must reach a generation where only a pulsar with its center in the red area remains/loops infinitely and everything else is destroyed. Yet in other, way cooler words:

> You have to construct a rocket to **move** the Sun and nothing else that was created in the process to remain.

The grid is infinite in every direction, i. e. runaway gliders still count as living.

EDIT: **Because all answers are correct and there is no easy way to choose which one is the most valid, I'm picking the one with the most votes. I hope this will not discourage others to post other interesting solutions.**

Comment: Do you have a solution to this? I'm inclined, at first glance, to think that it might not have one...

Comment: @Emrakul: This probably *is* solvable, because the [pre-pulsar](http://www.conwaylife.com/wiki/Pre-pulsar) should be a fairly simple pattern to generate. I have not actually attempted to solve this yet, though.

Comment: @Emrakul Yes, and if there is no solutions after several days I will post mine. Also if solutions differ then mine.

Comment: **its** center (twice). please?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

## 6 cells, 111 generations

I found 12 unique (up to reflection) 6-cell solutions:

> [image]

They all work by the same method as my previous 8-cell solution, forming a [house](http://www.conwaylife.com/wiki/House) one cell below the top of the base area at generation 6.  Here's an animation:

> [image]

There are no solutions with fewer than 6 cells (that stabilize within 200 generations).

## previous solution: 8 cells, 111 generations

> [image]

Comment: Awesome answer! Did you have a special method by which you created so many different solutions? Did you do them all by hand?

Comment: @theonlygusti I did them by having the computer test a subset of all possible initial conditions, after finding a sufficiently small set of initial conditions.

Comment: @2012rcampion Wow! 6 cells... You will discourage others to try finding other solutions ;)

Comment: Is cell golf a thing now? Do we need a new SE for this?

Comment: @jpmc26 Haha, I was wondering myself if PPCG would get some of these challenges; since Life is Turing complete this essentially amounts to programming in some sense...

Comment: @2012rcampion Would be worth asking on our (PPCG's) meta, but I'm pretty sure that both this and the previous question would have been on-topic challenges provided some winning criterion was chosen (fewest generations or fewest live cells, I guess).

Comment: @MartinBüttner I think maximum generations would be most challenging

Answer (score 54):

I have a solution:

> [image: Pattern]

I shamelessly stole the upper part from [BaSzAt's 8-cell sun destroyer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/31295), and, by trial and error, found a 7-cell lower part that generates a new pulsar without interfering with the upper half.  Like BaSzAt's solution, it takes 44 steps to gobble up the old sun, although the new one is already fully formed after 32 generations.  The center of the new pulsar is located just barely within the starting area, at the middle cell of the bottom row.

Here's an animation of it:

> [image: Animation]

In fact, the upper and lower parts of the pattern never really interact at all — they're just barely far enough apart to avoid interfering with each other.  They do, however, "quasi-interact", in the sense that, on some time steps, there's only a single cell layer separating them.  It just happens that, even though those cells have neighbors from both parts of the pattern, that never ends up making a difference as to whether they live or die in the next generation.

Comment: You didn't move the sun, you built your own and destroyed the original. It's kind of like the Sun of Theseus ;)

Comment: @WorldSEnder I assume that was a pun for Theseus' *son*, but I can't quite put my finger on it. Do you refer to Euripides' tragedy Hippolytus or Seneca's Phaedra? I'd love to enlighten myself. :)

Comment: @Oliphaunt it's a pun to the [ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus)

Answer (score 23):

### 19 cells, 41 generations, another humorous answer

EDIT: Only just noticed my answer to the previous challenge was logged in under the guest name user21465.

Continuing in the vein of humorous answers, here's another one. I thought it was going to be difficult and when I tried it I said ...

> [image: OH - blue]

Here's the animation

> [image: Pulsar - OH - blue]

Comment: Sorry to bother, but could you possibly change the colors of the red dots in the green field? You have accidentally hit upon a color combination that is almost unreadable to other people with partial red/green color blindness. (Like me.)

Comment: Oops! Should have remembered Ishihara tests from my earlier health and safety work. Colours are changed now.

Comment: Fantastic! Much better! Many thanx for the effort.

Comment: I think this is the best from multiple aspects: smaller number of generations and aesthetic of initial state =D

Answer (score 10):

### 21 cells, 111 generations, last humorous answer

As they can be weary, this is my last humorous answer to this question. Moving stars seems to be a no brainer ...

> [image: No brainer]

Here's the animation

> [image: Pulsar - no brainer]

Answer (score 6):

Posting my first solution, as I promised (69 generations):

> [image]