# Find the next sequence

Tags: pattern, visual

1)

[image: 1)]

2)

[image]

If someone already knew about this pattern, please let other people solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be

> [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life)

and I didn't know about it until

> I looked at the [top voted Puzzling questions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31247/game-of-life-kill-the-sun), lol

The pattern is:

> a yellow space with one or zero, or four or more adjacent yellow spaces is gray in the next pattern; 
>  
>  and each gray cell with two or three adjacent yellow cells becomes a yellow cell in the next pattern.

Using the pattern in the wiki article, the next pattern should be

> [image]

Comment: Where is that top voted question? i can't find

Comment: @user53678 edited in

Comment: thanks so i tried to delete this question but it says "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center"

Comment: @user53678 you don't have to delete a question after it's answered- in fact, you shouldn't.

Comment: that's true, my impetuous. but you seems to already knew about this site https://bitstorm.org/gameoflife/

Comment: @user53678 I googled "conway's game of life simulator." it's not hard to find.

Comment: ok, my apologies